# MySQL 5.6 losing days of data

Tags: mysql, rollback, data-loss

I work at a software company, and used as database Mysql 5.6

**Problem:** In recent days MYSQL has losing days of data, like a big rollback of datas in all tables, checking the MYSQL error log, only appears the follows messages: "database was not shutdown normally" and "[Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1181074230 and 1181074230 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1181075227 in the ib_logfiles ".

These messages could be related to the problem of data return days ago? May be some setting in my.ini is not recording transactional data? I never had this problem in MySQL 5.1, could it be a Mysql 5.6 bug?

The **my.ini**:

```
[mysql]
default-character-set = latin1

[mysqld]

sql_mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER"
collation-server = latin1_swedish_ci
character-set-server = latin1

## Caso queira alterar a porta do mysql edite abaixo
port = 3306

## Diretório de data do Mysql edite-o conforme o sistema em que está sendo instalado
datadir = C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6/data/

## Diretório base do Mysql edite-o conforme o sistema em que está sendo instalado
basedir = C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6

## Diretório que serão armazenados os ib_logfiles edite-o conforme o sistema em que está sendo instalado
innodb_log_group_home_dir = C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data/

## Local de armazenamento do tablespace, onde será criado o ibdata1 (antigo innodbdata). Edite-o conforme o sistema em que está sendo instalado
innodb_data_home_dir = C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6/data/

# Linguagem alterada para Pt-br
lc_messages=pt_BR
lc_time_names=pt_BR
# Ignora procura por DNS
skip-name-resolve

#Ignora cache em host, evitando que terminais fiquem bloqueados
skip-host-cache 
# Habilita agendador Mysql
event-scheduler=1

# Analise do banco http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/performance-schema.html
performance_schema

# Tamanho máximo da inserção em uma coluna
max_allowed_packet = 32M

# Número Máximo de conexões
max_connections = 150

# Valor Padrão 1 devido a ACID
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1

# Descomentar linha abaixo caso o mysql não esteja carregando tabelas que foram marcadas como corrompidas
# innodb_force_load_corrupted

# Linha que define force para iniciar banco de dados, usado somente
# quando o banco de dados esta com problemas. Pode ser usado de 1 a 6
# no lugar do X. Comece usando o 4 que e um dos melhores
#innodb_force_recovery=X

# Alocação de memória para grandes joins, só é plausivel quando os joins não tem index
join_buffer_size = 94M

# Buffer para grandes consultas que contenham order BY, agilizando o processo, por Default é 256k
read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M

# Buffer para grandes consultas que contenham order BY, agilizando o processo, por Default é 2M
sort_buffer_size = 4M

# Método de Escrita de dados e escrita de logs. Tenta O_DIRECT - Forma padrão fdatasync
# innodb_flush_method=O_DSYNC

# Pré-alocação de Memória para grandes querys
query_prealloc_size = 16M

# Habilitar cache para todos os SELECTS menos para os que informam SQL_NO_CACHE
query_cache_type=1

# Tamanho do maximo de cache para querys SELECT
query_cache_size = 80M

# Tamanho maximo de cache para querys individuais
query_cache_limit = 48M

# Usando um arquivo por tabela
innodb_file_per_table = 1

# Maximo de tabela abertas pelo Mysql
innodb_open_files = 1000

# Maximo de arquivos abertos pelo mysql
open_files_limit = 4096

# Salva no log de erros os deadlocks ocorridos
innodb_print_all_deadlocks

## Memória destinada ao cache de dados e index. Quanto maior for este parametro, menos recursos de I/O serão utilizados do HD.
## Utilizar 50 % da memória fisica do servidor, edite-o conforme o servidor em questão
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1024M

## ib_logfile(0/1): São as alterações que estão feitas nas transações innodb
## Utilizar 25% do informado do innodb_buffer_pool_size, edite-o conforme o servidor em questão
innodb_log_file_size = 200M

# Tamanho do cache que o innodb vai armazenar para gravação dos ib_logfiles. 
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M

# Tempo que o banco irá esperar até informar o timeout
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=180

## Concorrência entre Threads(cpu). É recomendado 2x o número de núclos do processador. Por padrão é 10. Edite-o conforme o servidor em questão
innodb_thread_concurrency=4

## Número de Threads(cpu) que poderão ser utilizadas para leitura. Utilizar 4x o número de núcleos do processador. Edite-o conforme o servidor em questão
innodb_read_io_threads=8

## Número de Threads(cpu) que poderão ser utilizadas para escrita. Utilizar 4x o número de núcleos do processador. Edite-o conforme o servidor em questão
innodb_write_io_threads=8

# Número de reutilização de threads, o recomendado é 5% do max_connections
thread_cache_size=7

## Capacidade IO do HD, por padrão é 200. Se SATA = 100. Se SAS = 200. Se RAID 5, 10 = 500. Edite-o conforme o servidor em questão, caso não tenha certeza qual HD está em uso deixe-o como está
innodb_io_capacity=200

# Tamanho da tabela temporária em disco
tmp_table_size = 128M

# Máximo que uma tabela temporária pode crescer
max_heap_table_size = 256M 

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 32M
```

Any help is appreciated